# saving updates of android studio for offline use next time

Tags: android, android-studio

As Android Studio is one of the heavy softwares which takes up high amount of space in HDD and so are its updates. Is there any way to save the updates done through the inbuilt options of Android Studio like updating to the latest sdk or api versions. So is there any way to save the files from currently installed files of Android Studio to save them separately for next time use or for use on another PC?

Comment: On Linux, Android Studio is just a collection of files, as is the Android SDK. You are welcome to copy those as needed (backups, migrate to a new hard drive, etc.).

Comment: But I'm currently using Windows 10, so is there any way to achieve this?